# Recreating an RNG in Python

Tags: python, matlab, random

I am trying to recreate a *multiplicative congruential algorithm* that is used in Matlab (Found it [here](http://www.physics.muni.cz/~jancely/NM/Texty/Numerika/Moler/random.pdf), section 9.2, read it for a little context)

Basically, I have 4 variables

```
a = 13
c = 0
m = 31
```

And this last one, which I can't format to code because it breaks the subscript:

x<sub>0</sub>`= 1`

And with those four, I'd like to reproduce something like this :

x<sub>k+1</sub> `= a *` x<sub>k</sub> `+ c mod m`

So far, I've got :

```
a = 13
c = 0
m = 31
base = 2 # Does not work with 0 for some reason
x = int(x='1', base=base)

for i in range(8):
    rand = a * x + c % m
    base += 1
    x = int(x='1', base=base)  
    print(rand)
```

And my output is :

```
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13...
```

Even though, according to the document, should be :

```
1, 13, 14, 27, 10, 6, 16, 22...
```

So I'm not sure if I completely misunderstood the question, or if what I'm trying to accomplish is simply not possible in Python, or if I'm just going bonkers, but I desperately need some advice. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `1` is going to be `1`, whatever the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the formula should be

x<sub>k+1</sub> = (a * x<sub>k</sub> + c) mod m

which isn't clear from the document, but if you use c mod m as they have it, you would be performing the same operation every time (0mod31). This segment of python code runs as it should:

```
a = 13
c = 0
m = 31

x = [1]

for i in range(1, 9):
    x.append( (a * x[i-1] + c)%m )
    print x[i],
```

13 14 27 10 6 16 22 7

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really seem to have misunderstood the algorithm. One question : I don't understand your use of a list for `x` : Is it the same as adding 1  to the radix of `x` (as the pdf seems to suggest)?

Comment: Right, so in this case the base is at x[0], which is set to 1 when I initialize the list as x = [1]. That way you can more easily refer to x<sub>k</sub> as just x[k]

Comment: Ah yes, ok. It's clearer now. Thanks for your time! :)